Is there a full implementation of Lexorank including the use of buckets and rebalencing
So I have been looking into what is the best (most efficient) way to store an users ordering (ranking) and I have come across Lexorank. (This is purely research. I understand that Lexorank should not be used in most situations).
I have found a couple of "example" implementations, but thats all they seem to be... Is there a full-on  implementation that:

uses buckets 0, 1, 2 in rotation;

Optionally: uses sub-sorting i.e. 1|zaaaaa:ba


includes a command that can rebalance in multiple "transactions"

I am also wondering how one would detect it's time to rebalance... (when it moves an item and sees that the gap is less than a set threshold?). And how would an users still be able to resort something while a rebalance is ongoing. Would it lock, until it's done?
(I assume a relational database is being used like MySQL or Postgres)
edit:
I am getting some votes to close this... please let me know why this is not a good question and how I can rephrase it perhaps instead of just voting "close".

"(This is purely research. I understand that Lexorank should not be used in most situations)." - It's what Jira allegedly uses in production - so how bad could it be?

I mean it more like I might not need it, because I am not building applications at that scale. And as I mentioned, I can't find complete solutions, that are not just reference implementations.
